# analog-input-mic unavaliable on archlinx on Macbook Pro

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa

I am trying to get my headset mic working on my 2015 Macbook Pro which is running arch. The device has a single port for both input and output. The output is working fine, I can hear from my headset but the microphone on the headset is never picked up. I tried playing around with HDAJackRetask but I don't think I am familiar enough with it to know if I'd made any progress. `pacmd` on the deivce shows:

```
ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-internal-mic>
```

The `analog-input-mic` always has `avaliable: no`. If I try to force the active port to be `analog-input-mic` rather than the internal one, it still pics up nothing.

Comment: Are you using PulseAudio?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: You can use the `pavucontrol` GUI. It gives you a fast overview of available options

Comment: I'm not what I'm looking for in this. Using `ncpamixer` or `pamix` both show only the built-in mic and not the headset mic.

Comment: I am not an expert about commands you quoted above but I used to use (and solve my issues with) `pavucontrol` utility. This is the reason why I point you toward that tool...

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Ok, in `pavucontrol` when I plug in the headset, the output devices show the `headphone (plugged in)` but the input devices show `headphones (unavailable). Not sure how to fix that.